# How to disable backups on Azure Sql Serverless database

Tags: azure-sql-database

Trying to reduce cost of a small azure sql serverless database by making the instance go into Pause mode, but I'm still getting charged around $1.5 per day with no operations on my end. I've disabled everything else that I can on the instance.  Looking at the query performance insight, it shows the database is constantly getting hit with backup-related operations and queries.

So how to disable backups?  I see no options to do this in azure.

Answer (score 1):

Agree backups and restores can prevent the database to auto-pause. Automated backups can be set to retention period of 1 using the portal (Backups option on the left panel), and that is the closest you can get to disable them. You cannot completely disable automated backups as it is required for Azure SQL to operate.

[image]

In addition, please note that applications connected to the database like SQL Server Managment Studio (SSMS) can prevent the database to auto-pause and SSMS can wake up the database by using only Object Explorer.

Other features like SQL Full-Text Search in use on the database can prevent also the database to go to auto-pause.

You can use Query Performance Insights to see the query executed to the database, including things like backups (exports) that can prevent the database to auto-pause also.

Finally, these Azure SQL or Azure features can prevent auto-pause also:

- Threat Detection
- Azure SQL Auditing
- TDE (Transparent Data Encryption that is enabled by default)
- Vulnerability Assessment
- Data Masking
- Data Discovery / Data Classification
- Automatic Tuning
- Database Copying
- SQL Data Sync

Comment: Why would the retention period affect how often the backups occur?  I'd think, if anything, reducing the retention period to 1 would cause the server to take backups more often, whenever the retention period expired.

Comment: Also, there's only one query and it's getting ran every other hour.  it shows in the Query Performance insights as:          (@backupTypeEquals nvarchar(1),@backupPathNotEquals nvarchar(3),@lastLsnLesserThanEqualTo decimal(35,0))SELECT TOP 1  [backup_metadata_uuid],................[compression_algorithm]  FROM [{----guid----value----}].[sys].[backup_metadata_store] WHERE (backup_type = @backupTypeEquals) AND (backup_path != @backupPathNotEquals) AND (last_lsn <= @lastLsnLesserThanEqualTo) ORDER BY backup_start_date DESC

Comment: The less backups are stored in that metadata file the faster that query will execute. That is the minimum you can set for that feature. However, one hour without any activity is enough for Azure SQL Serveless to get into auto-pause if you configured the serverless database to get into auto-pause at the minimum that is 1 hour. Please verify the list of features that prevent auto-pause including TDE which is enabled by default.

Comment: I had everything off that i could find had an option to turn off.  Some of the features on your list i do not see an option to turn off completely.  For instance the Data Masking had been auto masking a column in a table.  There was an option to turn off that instance of the masking.  But i saw no place that disabled Data Masking altogether.  So it seems like it could come back on if it finds a new eligible column.  Same with Data Discovery & Classification.  I wasn't able to find Threat Detection or Vulnerability Assessment.  Thank you.

Comment: To remove masking on a column from the Azure portal, click on the masking rule. In Edit Masking rule window, click on the Delete button and then click on Save. Remove them all.

Comment: Yes but my point is that won't actually permanently turn off the feature.  It could be turned back on with new columns.

Comment: Yes, that is by design. Same with automated backups.